# How my teacher is deriving this equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

I'm struggling in the resolution of this exercise. When he derives $f$, I don't understand the notation. What is $f$x1 supposed to mean? I think it means $\frac{\partial f1}{\partial x} $, being $f$1 the first component of the function. However, when he derives respect $y$ it keeps mantaining $f$x1 and that confuses me.

I've attached the resolution of the exercise in two pictures [Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY9k9.png) 
[Part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6GRZ.png) It's in Spanish, but here's the translation.

Consider the function $f:  \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R $, $C^1$ . Knowing that the equation satisfies the implicit function theorem and it allows us to obtain $z(x, y)$ in the neighborhood of any given point. Calculate...

Resoultion  Deriving respect $x$. Deriving respect $y$....

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Have you tried asking your teacher?

Comment: @JohnOmielan He said in class that it was the partial of x, but I don't understand why when he derives y keeps maintaining fx1 and not fy1

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You should also put those details, and any other pertinent ones, in your question. I'm not sure what your teacher has in mind, but perhaps you should ask again to explain further, or maybe somebody else will be able to better interpret what is intended.

Answer (score 1):

What your professor seems to mean (My mother tongue is English-I'm okay in French and Italian so I'm going by analogy) is $$u=x^2-y^2, v=y^2-z^2,f(u,v)=0.$$ 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0.$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2x,\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-2y,$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=2y-2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}.$$